# Scraping with BS4, find company name and ID

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently web scraping with **bs4, python** I would like to have some outputs to find 3 variables: Company Name, Product Id and Company ID.

This is what I have

**My code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Crazy-Hot-Selling-Multifunctional-Battery-Powered_60769168637.html')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

i = 0
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    i = i + 1
    print("v5 is",link.get('title'), i)

v6 = soup.select_one('meta[name="aplus-exdata"][content]')['content']
print("v6 is",v6)
```

**My output:**

```
**...**
v5 is None 54
v5 is None 55
v5 is Click to send an inquiry 56
v5 is None 57
v5 is None 58
v5 is Shenzhen ONULISS Technology Co., Limited 59
v5 is None 60
v5 is Trade Assurance 61
**...**
v6 is {"productId":"60769168637","companyId":"240628921"}
```

**The Output I want**

```
v5 is Shenzhen ONULISS Technology Co., Limited
Product Id: 60769168637
Company ID: 240628921
```

**Additional Notes**

-I'm using `v5,v6,vn variables` just as a reference to know where I am in the code, what really is important is the output company and the IDs.

-The `i` variable is justa a reference to understand how many times the output is repeated in the html. I don want to use the `i variable`  to find the company name all the time because maybe it is not in **position 59** in all different web pages.

**Thank you for your answers!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, you have to parse json before printing etc.
Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

page = requests.get('https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Crazy-Hot-Selling-Multifunctional-Battery-Powered_60769168637.html')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

company_name = soup.select_one('[data-aui="company-name"][title]')['title']

raw_content = soup.select_one('meta[name="aplus-exdata"][content]')['content']

#parse raw json
product_and_company_meta = json.loads(raw_content)

print("v5 is", company_name)
print("Product Id: ", product_and_company_meta['productId'])
print("Company Id: ", product_and_company_meta['companyId'])
```

Comment: I have a question, what is JSON actually doing here? Cleaning the data?

Comment: And another one, do you know where could I find additional information to study about how to use JSON for web scrapping?